# MikTex Package Updates via Proxy Server

Tags: miktex-update

My employer has a proxy server. I have gone to settings and input my proxy server settings as https:...... , the appropriate port, am asked for authentication settings, and the package update fails with error code 4. AS the proxy server is requesting autthenitication, I am assuming that I am inputting the settings correctly (but, maybe, indeed, not).

I have verified the proxy server settings, can hit that URL in a browser, but it fails via the MikTeX console.

Sorry, new MikTex user here, and am unable to update via a proxy server.

Is there a way to DL the required files, and update manually.

Comment: BTW, MikTex console 4.2